# React application not correctly recognizing authenticated state after Auth0 login

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, auth0

I have a react application that uses Auth0 for authentication. After login users are redirected to the original page (in this case "localhost:3000").

Auth0 appends an encoded string to the url after login and the application does not recognize that the user is logged in. Only when I manually enter the original url ("localhost:3000") does the application recognize that the user is logged in.

Here is my login method:

```
// src/auth/auth0-provider-with-history.js

import React from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Auth0Provider } from '@auth0/auth0-react';

const Auth0ProviderWithHistory = ({ children }) => {
  const domain = process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_DOMAIN;
  const clientId = process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID;

  const history = useNavigate();

  const onRedirectCallback = (appState) => {
    history.push(appState?.returnTo || window.location.pathname);
  };

  return (
    <Auth0Provider
    domain={domain}
    clientId={clientId}
    redirectUri={window.location.origin}
    onRedirectCallback={onRedirectCallback}
    >
    {children}
    </Auth0Provider>
  );
};
export default Auth0ProviderWithHistory;
```

And here is my login button:

```
import React from 'react';

import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

import { useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-react';

const LoginButton = () => {
    const { loginWithRedirect } = useAuth0();
    return (
    <Button variant='outlined'
        sx={{
            color: 'white',
            textTransform: 'none',
            borderColor: 'white',
            '&:hover': {
              borderColor: 'white',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)',
            boxShadow: 'none',
            },
            '&:active': {
            boxShadow: 'none',
            backgroundColor: 'none',
            borderColor: 'white',
          },            
        }}
        
        onClick={() =>
            loginWithRedirect()
        }>
        Log In
    </Button>
    );
};
export default LoginButton;
```

How do I prevent the url from being encoded, or get the application to recognize that the user is logged in without manually navigating to the root page?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue while following that same [tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/complete-guide-to-react-user-authentication/)— it's because `useNavigate`, which replaces `useHistory` in React Router v6, does not use `push` and `replace`. As a result, just remove `push`, keeping all other code the same, and it should redirect as expected while retaining the authenticated state.